# Angular ui.router display Bootstrap modal (popup)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

Someone know how ui.route with Boostrap works?

```
        .state('detalleProducto', {
            modal: true,
            templateUrl: 'views/productos/detalleProducto.html',
            controller: function($scope, $state) {
                $scope.close = function() { $state.go('^'); }
            }
    });
```

HTML

```
 <td class="text-center" nowrap>
 <a class="detalleProducto" href="#detalle_producto" ui-sref="detalleProducto" title="Detalle Producto">{{producto.code}}</a>
 </td>
```

It just display the page in the same ui-view.

How can I make the popup works?

Comment: why do you need to define a state inside a modal? what's your use case ?

Comment: I'm trying use a Bootstrap Modal (Popup) with Angular and inside load a HTML. I don´t know if i doing it right.

Comment: but what are you trying to show on the modal? most of the time you won't need a state, ui-bootstrap modal already provides you with an API to define a view and a controller